# mysql sorting by 2 columns dependencies

Tags: mysql, sorting, date

I'm searching for a trick, how to sort this:
I have 2 columns: status (numeric) and modification_date (date).

if status<9 (means for me if case is not closed) - it should be "order by status,modification_date

if status=9 (if case is closed) - it should be sorted "order by status,modification_date DESC

So - if I have cases not closed - they should be first in chronological order, but if they are closed - they should be in reversed order (newest first)

I hoped, that I can do UNION, but it's not possible to use "order by" in both sections (or maybe I'm doing something wrong)

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ORDER BY status,
         IF(status < 9, 1, -1) * modification_date
```

Comment: wow, I'm really impressed - it's  such simple solution :) Many, many thanks